# Power Automate Owners not found?

Tags: powershell, power-automate

Looking to get all owners for each flow in Power Automate. Randomly, a large portion of them are reporting no owners, but I can manually check that they do have owners. Help!

```
Remove-Variable * -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$Flows = Get-adminflow 

Foreach ($flow in $flows)
    {
        $flow.DisplayName
        Get-Adminflowownerrole -EnvironmentName $flow.EnvironmentName -flowname $flow.flowname
}
```

It can pull the names of all of them. They are all in different environments, so that isn't the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the Set-AdminFlowOwnerRole command?

```
Set-AdminFlowOwnerRole -PrincipalType Group -PrincipalObjectId [Guid] -RoleName CanEdit -FlowName [Guid] -EnvironmentName Default-[Guid]
```

**Description**
The Set-AdminFlowOwnerRole cmdlet sets owner permission to a flow, depending on parameters.

Link to Microsoft documentation:
[set-adminflowownerrole](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powerapps.administration.powershell/set-adminflowownerrole)